# WordBasic to modern find directory VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2016, wordbasic

Currently I'm having an issue with WordBasic my company recently decided to update their system from 2007 to Word 365 but, according to Google, WordBasic is a relic from Word 97 which no longer works on Word.

I need to retrieve the directory of where I saved my file but can't seem to find an alternative to my current (was working) code.

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Name = Jobnumber & " " & Jobname & " FDS V0_00.docx"
    .Show
    Dim Directory As String
    Directory = WordBasic.filenameinfo(.Name, 5)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

In word 2007 you are using VBA. The word `WordBasic` refers to an Object in the  VBA library:

[image]

This object was probably built with some of the old properties of the old `WordBasic`, but you should not care about this, as far as VBA is the one to handle it.

This code works for me in word 2016:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
        .Name = 1 & " " & 2 & " FDS V0_00.docx"
        .Show
        Dim Directory As String
        Directory = WordBasic.filenameinfo(.Name, 5)
    End With

End Sub
```

If for any reason it does not work, try `Directory = Word.Global.WordBasic.Filenameinfo(.Name, 5)`

Comment: Sadly this didn't work it give me the same issue 

Run-time error '76':

Path not found

Comment: @AlexGale - have you tried the `Word.Global.Wordbasic.F...` part?

Comment: Yes I think it's because Wordbasic is no longer recognised. if you know of another way of getting the directory from the user I think this might be the path I need to take

Comment: WordBasic is still supported - even in Word 2016.

Comment: @macropod - You should tag the OP in the comment, otherwise he will not read it.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you should be able to use the `Path` property of the `Document` object:

```
Directory = ActiveDocument.Path
```